# Adding Router To View Posts By Person's Name in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm new to web development, and I'm learning with Meteor.  I am pretty much following the Discover Meteor book, but when I veer off a bit, I get an error.

The following code works fine and the permalink works like it's supposed to:

router.js

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  waitOn: function() {return Meteor.subscribe('allPosts')}
});


Router.map(function() { 
    this.route('postsList', {path: '/'});

    this.route('postPage', {
        path: '/posts/:_id',
        data: function(){return Posts.findOne(this.params._id)}
    });
});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

But when I add the following to Router.map, it doesn't work correctly:

```
this.route('byName',{
    path: '/posts/:name',
    data: function(){return Posts.findOne({name: this.params.name})}
})
```

To be clear, I'll show my templates:

```
<template name = 'byName'>
    {{> postItem}}
</template>

<template name = 'postPage'>
    {{> postItem}}
</template>
```

And my post_item.html:

```
<template name = 'postItem'>
    <div class = "post">    
        Name: {{name}}, Post: {{post}}
        <a href = "{{pathFor 'postPage'}}">See Post</a>, 
        <a href = "{{pathFor 'byName'}}">By Name</a>
    </div>
</template>
```

When I click on "See Post" of the post

```
Name: Wonder Woman, Post: Hera, give me strength! See Post, By Name
```

I get the same post.  But when I click on By Name, I get

```
Name: , Post: See Post, By Name
```

with no values filled out.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `console.log()` statement to each route's data parameter...like this:

```
     this.route('postPage', {
          path: '/posts/:_id',
          data: function(){
            console.log("route -> postPage")
            return Posts.findOne(this.params._id)
          }
      });

      this.route('byName',{
          path: '/posts/:name',
          data: function(){
            console.log("route -> byName");
            return Posts.findOne({name: this.params.name})
          }
      });
```

I think you'll see the issue. I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve with your example, so I'm not sure if there's a specific way to fix your issue. However, I'll provide one option, so you can see that the following would work:

```
  this.route('byName',{
      path: '/posts/name/:name',
      data: function(){
        console.log("route -> byName");
        return Posts.findOne({name: this.params.name})
      }
  });
```

Notice how I gave it a different path to match?

In your example, your paths were essentially the same (they look different because of the parameter name, but they both point to `/posts/<string>`). As iron-router runs through the routes in order to handle the path correctly, it comes across the `postPage` route which matches the pattern first. That route looks for a single `Post` with an `_id` equal to some string (the `name` that was passed), and comes up empty. You could switch the order of how you define the routes (putting `byName` above `postPage`) and then `byName` would work and the other would be empty.

Hope that helps.